# javascript function that takes two inputs: an object and a key and returns the corresponding value for that key within the object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to create a JavaScript function that takes an object as input, and returns the values of all the keys in the object. Please kindly help review my code, I'm not getting the result I expect.

```
var james = {
    firstName: “James”,
    lastName: “John”,
    age: 40,
    job: “programmer”,
    married: false
};

function hasElObject(valObject, key) {
    var i = valObject.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (valObject[i] === key) {
            return valObject[i];
        }
    }
    return ‘key not found’;
}
var objectEl = hasElObject (['congratulations', 'top', 8, 90], 5);
log (arrayEl);

var retValue = getValue(mary,email);
log (retValue);
```

Comment: The title of the questions and the actual question you entered are asking for two different things.. which one do you actually want the function to do?

Comment: First off, your quotes are wrong in many places. Next, are you wanting to retrieve a value from an object or an array? Also, where is `arrayEl` and `getValue`?

Comment: Don't use MS Word (or any other word processor) for editing code.  You need to replace the `“`'s with *normal* quotes - `"`.

Comment: Judging from your attempt, you want to return the value if the key is found otherwise `'key not found'`. It's better to have a consistent approach like returning `null` if the key is not found. Also, you can use `hasOwnProperty(<str>)` to check if there is a key with name <str>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function hasElObject(valObject, key) {
  for (var k in valObject) {
    if (k == key)
      return valObject[k];
  }
  return 'key not found';
}

var jobOfJames = hasElObject(james, "job");
console.log(jobOfJames);
```

Comment: Mind your smart quotes!

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer is spot on. It works! Yes!

Comment: @rewritten - to distinguish cases of non-existing property and existing property with value `undefined`

Comment: that's precisely what you get with `key in valObject` (it returns `true` if there is a property with that key and `undefined` value)

Comment: Still there is the issue of being an _own_ property. You probably don't want to have `hasElObject({}, 'toString')` because it's a property of the prototype, not of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the native basic JS:

```js
function hasElObject(obj, key) {
  return obj.hasOwnProperty(key) ? obj[key] : 'key not found';
}
```